# Testing my package from Sonatype Staging

Tags: java, maven, gradle, sonatype

I have a library that is in maven central. When I push a new version it goes to the sonatype staging first before I have to promote it on to production.

I want to create a sample app that will pull the lib from staging so I can run some tests and what not before I promote it on to production. What URL would I use in my build.gradle for the staging repo?

Just to clarify I have tried using: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/staging/
But my project is not there yet, only versions I have promoted on to production are in this repo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The url https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/staging/ is actually correct. Before it will sync into staging you have to "close" it. That will sync it to staging where you can do the tests. Once you are satisfied simply "release" if you are happy, or "drop" if you need to redo it and start over with a new upload.